# How to get the values from specific row from SQLite Database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have the following table and it's working fine:

```
    public static final String BookID           = "books_ID";           
    public static final String Book             = "books";              
    public static final String Author           = "Authors";            
    private static final String BookAuthor_TABLE    = bookAuthor_Table";
    private static final String[] BookAuthor_AllKeys = new String[] { BookID, Book, Author };   
    private static final String BookAuthor_CREATE   =           
     "CREATE TABLE " + BookAuthor_TABLE + "("+ 
                                    BookID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                    Book + " TEXT," + 
                                    Author + " TEXT)";

......

......


    public ArrayList<String> getSpecificColumn(String book) {
        ArrayList<String> AUTHOR_ARRAYLIST;
        AUTHOR_ARRAYLIST = new ArrayList<String>();

        db = getWritableDatabase;       
        String WHERE = Book + "=" + book;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(BookAuthor_TAB, BookAuthor_AllKeys, WHERE, null, null, null, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String AUTHOR = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Author));
            AUTHOR_ARRAYLIST.add(AUTHOR);
        }

        return AUTHOR_ARRAYLIST;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
String book = “Jeff Jordan”
AUTHOR_ARRAY = MySQLITE_DATABASE.getSpecificColumn(book);
System.out.println(AUTHOR_ARRAY);
```

Why am I getting this error

```
(1) no such column: Jeff Jordan ?????
```

I've checked the table, and there was "Jeff Jordan" in the column Author.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals should be in `'single quotes'` or else they are taken as identifiers such as column names.

It's even better to use `?` parameters though:

```
String WHERE = Book + "=?";
Cursor cursor = db.query(BookAuthor_TAB, BookAuthor_AllKeys,
    WHERE, new String[] { book },
    null, null, null);
```

Comment: Jesus Christs, I am about to cry.  I've spent a lot of time searching online and doing trouble shooting, but it never worked.  You really helped me a lot.  Thank you so much!  I really appreciate it